# What is the effect of randomSeed on dimensionality reduction by random projection?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, random-seed, dimensionality-reduction

1) What is the effect of `randomSeed` parameter on `dimensionality reduction` by `random projection` in `weka`?

2) Secondly it is said that `dimensionality reduction` does not loss information, But I have observed that if we set the `numberOfAttributes` smaller, it improves accuracy, Whereas if we set `numberOfAttributes` close to current(actual) or a large value, whether it reduces accuracy?

Comment: Dimensionality reduction typically loses information. It's a form of lossy compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for "random number seed" to understand the random seed parameter.

Dimensionality reduction loses information, but the lower dimensionality can make things easier to optimize. The data lost can also be distracting noise, so don't be surprised to see the lossy approach improve performance sometimes. Just don't rely on it.

Comment: it means we are never sure that dimensionality reduction will improve accuracy or not however it will always optimize the classification process ?

Comment: No, otherwise we would always or never do it, but not just sometimes.

Comment: actually i have 146 dimension in my data. I have applied information gain already to reduce the dimension. I want to speed up my classification process without dropping accuracy. I came to know that only way to optimize the classification is to use quick learner and reduce dimensions however in my case they drop accuracy i.e. if i set dimension to reduce attributes to 80% , it reduces accuracy more than i set reduce attributes to 50%, Is there any other way around to optimize the classification process ?